# Custom info window in android map v2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to develop a custom info window in android map v2.I want to know how to remove the white background from the info window and how to set the background outside the circle radius to transparent black[image]

This is the xml for my custom info window

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">



</LinearLayout>
```

This is my code to make a custom info window

```
 getMap().getMap().setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.windowlayout,
                            null);

                    return v;
                }
            });
private SupportMapFragment getMap() {
        return ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    }
```

This is my marker click

```
@Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), point.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getMap().getMap().animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(8);

        getMap().getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
        getMap().getMap().animateCamera(zoom);
        Marker marker;
        getMap().getMap().clear();
        marker = getMap().getMap().addMarker(
                new MarkerOptions()
                        .draggable(true)
                        .position(point)
                        .title("Pick Up")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));

        // marker.setPosition(point);
        marker.showInfoWindow();
        rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

This is my map layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/data"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.muratonnet.map.TouchableSupportMapFragment" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <include layout="@layout/data_table" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the margin color of InfoWindow view of marker in google maps api v2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282718/change-the-margin-color-of-infowindow-view-of-marker-in-google-maps-api-v2)

Comment: Thanks Manish your answer did work it removed the white space

Comment: Do you know how to achieve the black background around the circle

Comment: Yo welcome! Buddy...

Comment: No buddy i have no idea...

Answer (score 7):

Please set your `infowindow` view at `getInfoWindow()` not `getInfoContents();`

By this you can remove default background of `infoWindow`.

So you have to inflate your view like this :

```
getMap().setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.windowlayout,
                            null);

                    return v;
                }

                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
                    return null;
                }
            });
private SupportMapFragment getMap() {
        return ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    }
```

Comment: If it worked then please marked as correct so that others can get help from your question. @SHUJATMUNAWAR