# Unable to set Custom info windows of Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I'm trying to set `Custom info windows` using this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518338/how-to-put-drawable-as-a-background-on-infowindow-google-maps-api-v2-for-androi).

Here's my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, ClickListenerChatFirebase, GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

public void showMap() {
        venueMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(venueLat), Double.parseDouble(venueLng))).title(venue.trim()));
        venueMarker.showInfoWindow();
        getInfoWindow(venueMarker);
    }

public AcceptedRequest(LayoutInflater inflater){
        this.inflater = inflater;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

        // Getting view from the layout file
//        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.venue_infowindow_background, null);

        TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.venue_txt);
        title.setText(marker.getTitle());

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}

}
```

Here's `venue_infowindow_background.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/venue_txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="venue"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**The problem** is that no change is happening and the info window is showing the default text-color and background-color.

Please help with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just directly call the `getInfoWindow()` method override.

You need to set the InfoWindowAdapter for the Google Map to your Activity, which implements the `GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter` interface.

```
public void showMap() {
    venueMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(venueLat), Double.parseDouble(venueLng))).title(venue.trim()));
    venueMarker.showInfoWindow();

    //This won't work:
    //getInfoWindow(venueMarker); 

    //Do this instead:
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(this);
}
```

In order to use a different layout for this Marker, you could inflate a different custom layout for all other Markers:

```
@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    View v = null;
    if (marker.equals(venueMarker)) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.venue_infowindow_background, null);
    } else {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_other_layout, null);
    }

    TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.venue_txt);
    title.setText(marker.getTitle());

    return v;
}
```

In order to use the "speech bubble" with the default Markers, and not with the one custom Marker, you can use `getInfoWindow()` with the custom Marker, and `getInfoContents()` for the default Markers. (More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31018671/4409409)). Something like this might work.:

```
@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    if (!marker.equals(venueMarker)) {
        return null;
    }
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.venue_infowindow_background, null);
    TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.venue_txt);
    title.setText(marker.getTitle());

    return v;
}

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
    if (marker.equals(venueMarker)) {
        return null;
    }
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_other_layout, null);
    TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.venue_txt);
    title.setText(marker.getTitle());

    return v;
}
```

Comment: this did the job but changed the background and textcolor of all the markers... how can I change it for 1 particular marker?

Comment: You could implement your `getInfoWindow()` override such that it inflates one layout for the one Marker, and a different layout for all other Markers.

Comment: but how? please elaborate a bit.

Comment: I updated the answer, take a look at the second code block.  If you want to make the other Markers look like the default, just make `some_other_layout.xml` use a white background and black text.

Comment: Great! That worked, but how can I make the same info window as the default one? Like with that down-pointing part just above the marker?

Comment: I just updated the answer with something that might work.  I didn't test it though!

Comment: it worked, but I'm getting a weird padding like shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282718/change-the-margin-color-of-infowindow-view-of-marker-in-google-maps-api-v2 How to remove this? Any idea?

Comment: I just updated the answer again, originally I had the logic wrong regarding when to use the speech bubble.  Take a look at the latest code.

Comment: yeah, but the weird padding is still there... that is the problem now :|

Comment: any solution regarding weird padding?

Comment: @HammadNasir There is no easy solution.  Basically, if you're using the default white "speech bubble", you will need to use a light background.  For a dark background speech bubble, you will need to do a custom one yourself.  Basically, use `getInfoWindow()`, and in the layout xml, define a custom drawable as the background that has the shape of a speech bubble (you could use png or xml drawables).  You might need to use Photoshop to make custom png assets if you can't find anything pre-made.